# how to load external libraries in angular app with webpack based setup

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm trying to load external libraries into my angular app which is a webpack

based setup.

I already tried these:

1. `yarn add ngx-extended-pdf-viewer`
2. import the module:

```
import { NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule } from 'ngx-extended-pdf-viewer';
```

3. Now normally in angular-cli app I should add those files into angular.json:

```
   "scripts": [
      "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf.js",
      "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf.worker.js",
      "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/viewer.js"
    ]
```

and

```
      "assets": [
      {
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/locale",
        "output": "/assets/locale/"
      }
    ]
```

but in my case it is a webpack based setup so there is no angular.json structure file to do that.

I already tried to load load those files in webpack.common.js like above but it is not working:

```
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: './node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf.js', to: 'ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf.js' },
            { from: './node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf.worker.js', to: 'ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf.worker.js' },
            { from: './node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/viewer.js', to: 'ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/viewer.js' },
        ]),
```

I do not know where I should load those files to make the plugin work.

Comment: Importing `NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule` should be enough. That module should take care of bundling the files. If that doesnt work, why not just import those files as well? :) If the scripts dont support import, you can require them.

Comment: @enf0rcer where i should do that ?